# Primefaces datatable required fields not work

Tags: primefaces, datatable, required-field

I would create a check input information about specified in:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml

I create a dataTable with a lot required field (inputText with attribute required="true") and a p:message into datatable section.
Problem is when I click on button to save data: I don't see alert message in my page but starting execution of associated bean.
Why?

My code in .xhtml is this:

```
<h:form>  
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
<p:dataTable var="myAtt"
             value="#{myBean.attributes}"
             rowIndexVar="myAttIndex">
    <h:inputHidden value="#{myAtt.value}" rendered="#{myAtt.description == 'XXX'}" />
    <p:column rendered="#{myAtt.description == 'XXX'}">
        <h:outputText value="*" rendered="#{myAtt.required}" />  
    </p:column>
    <p:column rendered="#{ myAtt.description == 'YYY'">
        <p:fragment rendered="#{myAtt.description == 'ZZZ'">
            <p:fragment rendered="#{myAtt.value == 'value1'}">
                <p:inputText size="#{myAtt.maxLength}" 
                             value="#{myAtt.value}"
                             rendered="#{myAtt.const == 't1'}"
                             required="true"
                             id="idText">
                    <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" update="@form"/>
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="idText"/>
            </p:fragment>
        </p:fragment>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable> 
<br />
<p:commandButton value="Create" action="#{myBean.commit()}" process="@this" update=":MYPAGE"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code? A lot of things can go wrong and seeing your code saves us the trouble of guessing what went wrong in your case.

Comment: Update question. Thanks

Comment: Do you realize that with time nobody wants to help you here, as you never show any appreciation for the help people provide? Points are free you know

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indicate an id for the `h:form` : `<h:form id="myForm">`

And in the update of the `p:commandButton` you have to indicate the id of the form : `update=":MYPAGE :myForm"`

**EDIT**

According to the PrimeFaces users guide 3.5, the attribute `action` will be called when the user clicks on the button.

[image: commandButton]

Comment: Doesn't work. Calling always bean in create button and I don't see alert messages...

Comment: In your code there is not the end tag `</h:form>` for the `<h:form>`, did you forget it in your post ?

Comment: I forget in my post. Now it works, I removed global p:messages in head and I set only <p:message for="..."/> for each component.

Comment: I observe that my commandButton is always called even if there are alert messages. Why? And then attribute value required in my dataTable are built with null value or "", so PrimeFaces consider it as valued and doesn't show alert message..

Comment: Glad it works for you. The `action` attribute will be called even if they is some "alert messages" (I edited my post).